# Add SCNText to SCNPlane

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

i am adding an SCNPlane using

```
artPlane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(widthRequired) * 0.0254,
                        height: CGFloat(size["width"]!) * 0.0254)

    artworkNode = SCNNode(geometry: artPlane)

    artworkNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "loadingar")

    let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1, 0)
    let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
    artworkNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(translation, rotation)

    artworkNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    artworkNode?.simdTransform = matrix

    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(artworkNode!)
```

Now i want to add an SCNText to the center of the above plane, how do i specify the position of the new textNode so that its in the center of the Plane?